# Nusoap nested arrays seem to fail?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to communicate with TargetProcess via their Soap services. When I do a simple request such as a "read" it works.

For example

```
// Some code...
$client = soapclientnusoap(path to my service...);

$client->call("RetrieveAll");

// Get nice results...
```

Next.. when I try to do a bit more complex operation, it works too...

```
// Some code...
$client = soapclientnusoap(path to my service...);

$params = array("Name"=>"Sample project");
$client->call("CreateProject", $params);

// Get nice results...
```

It works too..

HOWEVER, when I do nested arrays, it fails

```
// Some code...
$client = soapclientnusoap(path to my service...);

$params = array('entity'=>
    array("Name" => "Bug name")
);

$client->call("CreateBug", $params);

// Error..
```

The only difference is that the basic commands don't have params or have a one level of params, and the last one has a nested params.

Any clues ?!!!

Thank you.

This is my error
    [faultstring] => Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in the XML document. ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

And this is the request (headers removed)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><Create xmlns="http://targetprocess.com"><entity><ID/><BugID/><Name>TEST Bug</Name><Description>Some words about the bug</Description><StartDate/><EndDate/><CreateDate>2011-02-11T17:57:21</CreateDate><ModifyDate/><LastCommentDate/><NumericPriority/><Effort/><EffortCompleted/><EffortToDo/><TimeSpent/><TimeRemain/><LastCommentUserID/><OwnerID/><LastEditorID/><EntityStateID/><PriorityID/><ProjectID>131</ProjectID><IterationID/><ParentID/><ReleaseID/><SeverityID/><BuildID/><UserStoryID/></entity></Create></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Notes:

1. I am using the latest Nusoap version on php5.2 that means I had to rename soapclient from nusoap, tu soapclientnusoap.
2. I can't use native php5 SoapClient because the service I am accessing is requesting some headers and to be honest, I already spent 5 hours and was not able to generate the headers as expected.. maybe I should focus on this but I can't think on what else to do, so I am stuck with Nusoap.